# Add an activity indicator on a uiwebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a viewDidLoad which creates a web view and starts an activity indicator. How do I make the activity indicator stop only when the web page appears? How do I add words to the activity indicator like "Loading"?

```
// Create the UIWebView
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:webView];

// Start the throbber to check if the user exists
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityView.center = CGPointMake([self screenWidth] / 2.0, 370.0);
[activityView startAnimating];
activityView.tag = 100;
[self.view addSubview:activityView];

NSString* url = @"http://google.com";
NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30];


// Remove activity view
UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:100];
//[viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> How do I make the activity indicator stop only when the web page appears?

Your object can become `delegate` for `webView` to listen to `-webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method. So:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Create the UIWebView
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView.delegate = self; // Here is the key
    ...
}

...

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.view viewWithTag:100].hidden = YES;
}
```

You may also implement `-webViewDidStartLoad:` to show activity indicator instead of showing it in `-viewDidLoad` method.

> How do I add words to the activity indicator like "Loading"?

You should create a separate `UILabel`, there is no way to add text to standard `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Comment: This gives me a warning though since Privacy Controller is a view controller : webView.delegate = self; // Here is the key

Comment: How do I fix that to remove the warning?

Comment: Whoops forgot to add this to the header file <UIWebViewDelegate>

Answer (score 34):

Make a loading View:

```
@implementation yourViewController{;
    UIView* loadingView;
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad`:

```
loadingView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 400, 80, 80)];
loadingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0. alpha:0.6];
loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityView.center = CGPointMake(loadingView.frame.size.width / 2.0, 35);
[activityView startAnimating];
activityView.tag = 100;
[loadingView addSubview:activityView];

UILabel* lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 48, 80, 30)];
lblLoading.text = @"Loading...";
lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lblLoading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:lblLoading.font.fontName size:15];
lblLoading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[loadingView addSubview:lblLoading];

[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
```

This view will look like this:

[image]

Be careful, if you want to use the cornerRadius, you have to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework, and of corse before import, add `QuartzCore` framework to your project !

Detect when webview stop loading:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [loadingView setHidden:YES];
}
```

you have to implement `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol, and

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

and make it visible:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

 [loadingView setHidden:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 9):

[image]

If you are looking for this on Swift, here it is:

```
var boxView = UIView()

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView_Pages: UIWebView) {

    // Box config:
    boxView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 115, y: 110, width: 80, height: 80))
    boxView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    boxView.alpha = 0.9
    boxView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    // Spin config:
    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
    activityView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 12, width: 40, height: 40)
    activityView.startAnimating()

    // Text config:
    let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 80, height: 30))
    textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
    textLabel.font = UIFont(name: textLabel.font.fontName, size: 13)
    textLabel.text = "Loading..."

    // Activate:
    boxView.addSubview(activityView)
    boxView.addSubview(textLabel)
    view.addSubview(boxView)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView_Pages: UIWebView) {

    // Removes it:
    boxView.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Don't forget to call UIWebViewDelegate:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
```

And set the delegate for the webView on the viewDidLoad:

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

Header:

```
    UIView * indicatorView;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
@property UILabel* label;


-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


indicatorView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.mapView.frame.size.width/2-40, self.mapView.frame.size.height/2-30 , 80, 60)];
indicatorView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f];
[self.mapView addSubview:indicatorView];
indicatorView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
[[indicatorView layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[[indicatorView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
indicatorView.clipsToBounds=YES;


activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(indicatorView.frame.size.width/2-15, 8, 30, 30)];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
//activityIndicator.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
[indicatorView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];


UILabel *loadingLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, indicatorView.frame.size.height-22, indicatorView.frame.size.width, 20)];
loadingLbl.text = @"  Loading...";
//loadingLbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
loadingLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
loadingLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
loadingLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YanaR-Bold" size:10];
[loadingLbl  setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0f]];
[indicatorView addSubview:loadingLbl];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.